# Is it possible to sort an array in O(n) if there are only elements from 1 to n?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Let's say the comparison of elements in array takes O(n), is it possible to sort the array in O(n) when it has elements starting from 1 to n?

We need to create an algorithm like that but don't know if it's even possible. I could think of one in O(n^2).
I'm not asking for the algorithm, will take my time to create one but need to know if it's possible at all.

Comment: Duplicates included or not?

Comment: comparison takes O(n)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm  Look at `Non-comparison sorts`

Comment: So given exactly n elements from 1...n, you already know what the sorted order is. So just create that...

Comment: I just went through a Data Structures course. Your best sorting on an array is going to be n lg n (assuming random data)

Comment: The minimum for a comparison-based sort is O(n log n). The obvious O(N) algorithm for numbers in a limited range would be a bucket sort.

Comment: @theblindprophet: that's only for *comparison*-sorts. Faster algorithms exists if you know something about the data in advance.

Comment: Correct, assuming random data

Comment: The numbers from 1 to n ARENT sorted, forgot to mention that.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what *Let's say the comparison of elements in array takes O(n)* means, comparison of numbers is - except for very theoretical work - considered to be done in O(1).

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem
But how you know it's done in O(1)? Yes it's a theoretical question actually. So it wouldn't work in O(n), right?

Comment: @frytkii: the point is that on most machines an `int` is actually a 32-bit number. When using a fixed wordlength, comparison of elements is done in O(1). If you would perform comparison on unbounded integers (like `BigInteger`), comparison of two *numbers* is done in O(b) with b the number of bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely possible to do so, you simply create an array with counters and count the number of times element *i* occurs, since the elements range from *1* to *n*, you know this counter has length *n*.

Next there is the generate step, where you simply generate *k<sub>i</sub>* elements *i* if you have encountered *k<sub>i</sub>* such elements.

Example code in Java:

```
int[] data = {5,1,2,4,5,1,2,3};

//assuming data contains only values from 1 to n (included) with n the length
public static int[] sort_int_limited (int[] data) {
    int n = data.length;
    int[] counters = new int[data.length];

    //counter phase
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        counters[data[i]-1]++;
    }

    //generate phase
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < counters[i]; j++) {
            data[k++] = i+1;
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

[**jDoodle demo**](http://jdoodle.com/a/Tq)

As @Aivaen says in [his/her comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686263/is-it-possible-to-sort-an-array-in-on-if-there-are-only-elements-from-1-to-n/37686405#comment62849978_37686405), this algorithm is called *counting sort*.

Comment: Btw, this algorithm is called [Counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

Comment: @Aivean: I've added it to the answer. Didn't knew the name, but eventually this algorithm is rather simple and therefore definitely existed already.

Comment: Thank you all very much for sharing your ideas and knowledge with me, really appreciate that!

Answer (score 1):

Yes "Bucket sort":
    declare array of size n call it arr, set it to zeroes,

2.for each value in the given input array:

```
  add one in arr in the index that is equal to the value
```

declare new array out:
declare int k =0

3.for  i in input array

```
if arr[inputarray[i]>0 do:

    1.out[k]= arr[i]
    2.arr[inputarray[i] = arr[inputarray[i] -1
    3. k=k+1
```

return out

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what is meant by "comparison of elements in array takes O(n)". If the size of an array is "s", then the number of possible comparisons is s things taken 2 at a time.

The sorts that can be performed in O(s) time don't compare elements, usually they count them or they use element values as indices.

This could possibly be a trick question, since the number of elements is not specified. Let s = size of array, then a counting sort could sort the array in O(s) time (not O(n) time).